# How to compare managed and unmanaged Strings?

Tags: string, visual-c++, .net-2.0

I have an application that uses managed `System::String` in the UI elements, but then refers to un-managed (read: legacy) code for the more complex computation.

Additionally, there is not a consistent encoding for the strings - managed strings can be either regular `"strings"` or Unicode `L"strings"` and un-managed strings come in all of `char *, wchar_t *, std::string, std::wstring` varieties.

What is the best way to compare the various flavors of strings? I'm hoping that I can do this without having to implement half a dozen comparison methods like

```
int compare(System::String ^ s1, char * s2);
int compare(System::String ^ s1, wchar_t * s2);
int compare(System::String ^ s1, std::string s2);
int compare(System::String ^ s1, std::wstring s2);
int compare(char * s1, System::String ^ s2);
int compare(wchar_t * s1, System::String ^ s2);
...
```

The primary purpose will be equality comparisons, so if those are significantly easier to do, then I would like to see those answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an excellent MSDN article covering this topic in both directions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42zy2z41.aspx

And here's the Marshal class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atxe881w.aspx

With this, I would suggest defining various managed code methods that take the different types of native strings, converts them into a managed string, then compares them.

Unfortunately, I see no way to get around permutating the different native string types. They are literally different data types, even though they both represent what we call a string. And if it messes up the conversion, you can get into some dangerous territory.

Also, I would drop `std::string` out of the running, since you can easily call `c_str()` to get a `const char *` out. Same for `std::wstring` and `wchar_t`.

Here's an example of one:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

public static int NativeCompare(System::String ^ s1, char * s2)
{
    System::String ms2 = Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)s2);
    return s1.CompareTo(ms2);
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to choose to do the comparison using System::String over any of the alternatives? I have no idea if using C-style strings would be better, but I can't imagine it being worse.